# XSL-FO calculated column-width depending on the font

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, column-width

I am going to show the |label:| variable-value | each one in its own column, but I want to calculate the column-width of the '**label:**' so the width is just enough to fit the label no matter its font or the length of the label.

I initially thought to do something like `string-length($label)` and make this `em` units; however `em` may be too wide as it's the width of an '**m**' character, so if the label is "iiii" the allocated space would be "mmmm".

If I don't find another way to get the right width using `em` would be the less bad option I have so far.

Comment: How should the result be if you have two or more label/value couples (with different-sized labels)? What FO processor are you using? (this could have an impact on what's available to solve your problem)

Comment: Put each line in its own table. Set the block in the first cell to keep together within line. No calculations necessary.

Comment: Yes, each line is going to be a table, and there is going to be | label1: | value1 | label2: | value2 | label3: | value3 |, etc. I am creating a template able to display up to ten label-value couples. For instance, the first couple will use 30% of the table that should be split into what ever label-1 uses and the rest for value-1.

Comment: ... so what width to give to each label column or its partner value column if for instance label-1 width plus value-2 width should total 30% of the table width.

Comment: ... another alternative would be to use only one column for both label and value and use two inlines, or something else, inside one cell, so I can give different formats to each one. Any ideas?

Comment: Having label and value in a single cell would be the easiest option.

Comment: If you are talking of "tables" just because you want a **border** around label and value, then you don't need an fo:table at all; just use fo:inline and set border on it.